# normal distribution expected value and variance of waiting times

Tags: probability

Imagine a student can commute from home to their university by bus where the waiting time for the bus is normally distributed w/ mean of 5 minutes and sd of 1. When leaving campus and heading back home, 75% of the time the student heads back in the afternoon with the wait time distributed as a normal rv with mean 8 and sd 2. 25% of the time the student takes the night bus home with wait time mean of 12 and sd 4. All wait times are independent.

a) What is the expected daily total wait time after a commute to and another one from campus?

b) What is the variance of the daily commuting time?

c)  What is the probability the total wait time for a commute is less than 15 minutes?

---

With each part above, I'm confused about how to incorporate the fact that there are two mutually exclusive events (taking either the afternoon bus or night bus back home).

For a), can we simply take the expectation of the sum of the three rvs and multiply E[Tafternoon] by 0.75 and E[Tnight] by 0.25?

For b), I'm guessing we cannot do this but I am not sure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks updated post

Comment: The wording in part (a) is unclear. Have you heard about mixture distributions?

Comment: I think a) means the expected value of the wait time back and forth.

Comment: Mixture, no, I haven't, I'll look into it.

Comment: Though this is just a intro calc based prob and stats course and I don't think we covered that

Comment: All you really need is the total law to answer this question. For example, if $Y$ is the wait time for the return trip, then $Y|\text{Afternoon}\sim \mathcal{N}(8,2^2)$ and $Y|\text{Night}\sim \mathcal{N}(12,4^2)$. Using these facts along with the total law of expectation you can compute $\mathbb{E}(Y)$

Comment: Thanks.  We haven't learned that unfortunately (the law of total expectation).  Only the law of total probability and very basic stuff about the normal distribution,  linearity of E and Var (when independent).

Comment: Got it. Well, you can use the same information to find the cdf of $Y,$ namely $F_{Y}(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$, then differentiate to get the pdf of $Y$. Once you have the pdf of $Y$ you can then find its expected value.

Comment: Hmm. How might we get the cdf from the conditional probabilities?